# Dell Inspiron speaker connector repair

Tags: dell-inspiron, laptop-repair, connector

I have this Dell Inspiron N5010 laptop.

Can I replace the connector using another, because I tore the cable out of it.

Here is an image of my motherboard:

[image: motherboard]

Now, the connector pointed with the arrow needs to be fixed.

Can anyone identify the name of the connector, or give me a suggestion of how can I glue, solder or do anything about it, because otherwise I need to buy new speakers just for the connector.